# PHP less then or equal to not working

Tags: php, passwords

I'n trying to set a minimum number of characters you can have in a password, this is what I'm using

```
 if (strlen($pass1 <= 6)){
    echo "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
}
```

And if my password is less then 6 or over 6 it still echoes the message. I'm pretty sure I'm setting everything up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong brackets!

```
if (strlen($pass1) <= 6) {
    echo "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to do.

```
   if (strlen($pass1) <= 6 ){
```